# In unity, how to fetch and display real-time data from API?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code for fetching data from API:

```
IEnumerator GetData_Coroutine(){
        string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/new";
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url)){
        yield return request. SendWebRequest();
        if (request. isNetworkError || request. isHttpError)
            Debug.Log("error");
        else{
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
            Root varr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(request.downloadHandler.text);
            Debug.Log(varr.one);
        }
        // outputArea.text = request.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }
```

I want to fetch data in real-time, if API update I want to see those updates in unity too. I have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Well poll-checking is one of the existing approaches - especially in cases where you are not the one who implements the server: Simply repeat the request in a certain time interval (or as soon as the previous one finished)

```
IEnumerator GetData_Coroutine()
{
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/new";

    while(true)
    {
        using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return request. SendWebRequest();

            if (request. isNetworkError || request. isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log("error");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
                var varr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(request.downloadHandler.text);
                Debug.Log(varr.one);

                outputArea.text = varr.one;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This depends of course if your server e.g. has some limits etc so you might want to throw in an additional

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
```

within the `while` loop to throttle down the requests a bit.

---

Alternatively look into [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) and [SignalR](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-signalr-from-scratch/) where you can basically maintain a continuous connection and listen to received packages (basically like in TCP) - might be more complex to setup though and depends on your server implementation as well.